# I'm looking for an adjective which means "few people know", "only professionals know"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm looking for an adjective which means "few people know" or "only professionals know".

Especially, I want to describe settlement & clearing fields as "__________ fields".

Here is a full sample sentence. "I needed to learn the business model of XXXXX (the name of company which provides clearing services). However, because settlement & clearing is a very _____ field, it was very difficult to research by myself."

I came up with a word "esoteric" and found other posts discussing this word, but I'm not quite sure this word can be applied to context above for the following two reasons.
1. I thought "esoteric" means something like very eccentric hobbies, not formal things. Therefore, if I refer to settlement & clearing as "esoteric fields", it may sound humorous.
2. I'm not sure how frequently this word is used by native speakers.

Comment: Why are you not sure about *esoteric*? Please [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/526544/edit) to include that as well.

Comment: How about "recondite?"

Comment: The word "esoteric" is certainly not restricted to describing informal situations and hobbies - why do you think it is?

Comment: What about "Arcane"?

Comment: What do 'settlement' and 'clearing' mean? Are these about colonization and farming? Or is it more abstract, implying fields (not literal farm fields but fields of knowledge) where that knowledge is complicated and settlement and clearing are more about clarifying and setting up good pedagogy? 'esoteric' leans towards the latter, but your choice of 'settlement' and 'clearing' lean toward the literal 'farming' field.

Comment: Have you considered "specialised" or "specialized" depending on your spelling preference?

Comment: Settlement and clearing are specialized fields related to banking, of the sort of activity performed by the Bank for International Settlements.

Comment: What about subject-specific or case-specific?

Comment: *Esoteric* is too extreme for this context. Settlement and clearing are major financial functions that employ tens of thousands of people, maybe even hundreds of thousands, depending on how the work is defined.

Comment: very access-protected field; restricted field; safeguarded field

Answer (score 3):

I’d go with *specialized*. The knowledge is not arcane or abstruse; it is merely possessed by few people.

specialized

(speʃəlaɪzd  )

ADJECTIVE
Someone or something that is specialized is trained or developed for a particular purpose or area of knowledge.
COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/specialized

Answer (score 1):

**Obscure** can work.

> relatively unknown

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obscure)

Answer (score 1):

An *[abstruse](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abstruse?s=t)* field is one that is

> hard to understand; recondite; esoteric

Answer (score 1):

"...only professionals know.", because settlement & clearing is a very _____ field, it was very difficult to research by myself."

A **technical field** comes to mind.

> - [**technical**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/technical) - marked by or characteristic of specialization. (technical language)
> - [**technical**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/technical) - Used in or peculiar to a specific field or profession; specialized: technical jargon.
>     Requiring advanced skills or specialized equipment: technical mountain climbing.

- It's a job that requires technical knowledge.
- A book about such technical fields as engineering, physical and applied sciences.